# How to use sed to replace characters at specific line positions?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to process some files and I want to turn these files to .csv file, so I need to replace some specific characters(space in my case) with comma(',').
I believed that this can be done with sed or awk, but I failed to write correct sed command.

For example, an input file looks like below (only two lines for example)

```
 112 322432 434543    4555 3223
 adg gdasgg dagdag    gdag gdsg
 ...
```

Note that data in an input file is not necessarily separated by exactly one space, but it is guaranteed the input file is valid for replacing characters.
And I need to replace every character at column position 3, 10, 17, 25 in each line.
The corresponding output file should be like this

```
 112,322432,434543,   4555,3223
 adg,gdasgg,dagdag,   gdag,gdsg
 ...
```

By the way, is it possible to write a sed script (instead of hard code) that we can define an array containing positions that we need to replace space with comma.

===================

My bad, replacing continuous spaces does not work for my case.

`abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde
abcde abcde    de        bcde`

The above lines show the problem I am facing, some data fields might be empty but can not be ignored. Luckily, the input file guaranteed that all data fields are placed at correct position according to project document (Every field's length is given and they are separated by a single space, although in input file there may be continuous spaces because of difference between required length in document and actual length of data).

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -r 's/([^ ]) /\1,/g' File
```

Find string matching a non space character followed by a space then replace with the character + `,`

Answer (score 2):

> And I need to replace every character at column position 3, 10, 17, 25 in each line.

I suppose that means that there may be significant space characters either preceding or following the space delimiters, so that the position on the line is the only reliable way to identify the characters to sub.  I also take it that you don't actually care what character is at those positions in the original file.  If you truly must use character numbers to identify the locations for substitutions, then you can do it this way:

```
sed -e 's/\(.\{3\}\)./\1,/'  \
    -e 's/\(.\{10\}\)./\1,/' \
    -e 's/\(.\{17\}\)./\1,/' \
    -e 's/\(.\{25\}\)./\1,/' \
    input > output
```

Each fragment performs one substitution at the designated location by matching all the characters up to and including the substitution position and capturing those preceding the substitution position, and replacing them with the captured characters plus a comma.

Alternatively, this is equivalent:

```
sed -e 's/\(.\{3\}\).\(.\{6\}\).\(.\{6\}\).\(.\{7\}\)./\1,\2,\3,\4,/' \
    input > output
```

Comment: Sorry. Please ignore the first space in each line, and I counted the index starting from 0.

Comment: @RobinWang, yes, I realized.  The indexes in the above code already incorporate that understanding, but I bungled the boundaries of the capturing groups.  I have updated the code to fix that, and also provided a somewhat condensed version.  The condensed version is harder to correlate to your requirement, but might run slightly faster if you need to process lengthy files.

Answer (score 1):

WIth GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/([^ ]) /,"\\1,","g")}' file
 112,322432,434543,   4555,3223
 adg,gdasgg,dagdag,   gdag,gdsg

$ awk -v pos='5 12 19 27' 'BEGIN{split(pos,a)} {for (i in a) $0=gensub(/./,",",a[i])} 1' file
 112,322432,434543,   4555,3223
 adg,gdasgg,dagdag,   gdag,gdsg
```

Your count was off by 2 when you said you wanted to replace the chars at positions 3, 10, 17 and 25:

```
$ awk -v pos='3 10 17 25' 'BEGIN{split(pos,a)} {for (i in a) $0=gensub(/./,",",a[i])} 1' file
 1,2 3224,2 4345,3    45,5 3223
 a,g gdas,g dagd,g    gd,g gdsg
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use `awk` handy `FIELDWIDTH` variable to specify column width, using `-F` to remove the space separator, and `-v OFS=,` to replace it with a coma:

```
 awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="3 7 7 8 4" -F" " -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' file
```

This returns:

```
 112,322432,434543,4555,3223,
 adg,gdasgg,dagdag,gdag,gdsg,
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `sequence of spaces` with `,`

Example with `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/ +/,/g' File
```

This will give you the `CSV` output. But assumption here is that the data itself doesn't have any space in it.

Comment: That breaks the formatting. You can clearly see in the example they want to preserve multiple spaces.

Comment: I assume formatting is not the priority here, rather, the objective is to generate csv file. Formatting came as part of his idea for solving this.

Comment: My bad, I did not clearly clarify that the formatting is actually important, because data field in original file are placed at certain position with certain length. Every data field has its own length and space is used to fill the remain length(some data may even be empty but we can not omit them). And that's why data is not necessarily split by a single space. Replacing continuous spaces does not work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
sed -r 's/(.{3})./\1,/; s/(.{10})./\1,/; ...'
```

In other words, you replace `n` characters followed by another character, with the original `n` characters followed by a comma. You need a statement like that for each index, which is inconvenient. However, you can automate this translation, also using `sed`:

```
 echo 3 10 17 25 | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sed -r 's#(.*)#s/(.{\1})./\\1,/;#;' | sed -rf- input
```

You can eliminate the first call of `sed` at the cost of a slightly more complex program:

```
echo 3 10 17 25 | sed -r 's#([^ ]+)( |$)#s/(.{\1})./\\1,/;\n#;P;D'  | sed -rf- input
```